# Angular function return variable wrapped in quotes displays as text instead of renders/using different scheme that does not break css

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, wrapper, quotes

I have in my Angular template:

```
<ul>
{{ getRoundHtml(roundIndex) }}
</ul>
```

which calls a function in my component:

```
  getRoundHtml (indexRound){
    this.roundHtmlStr = '';
    console.log("INDEXR:", indexR);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.entries/Math.pow(2,indexRound); i++){
    this.roundHtmlStr = this.roundHtmlStr + `
         <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>\n 
         <li class="game game-top winner">Creighton <span>50</span></li>\n
         <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>\n
         <li class="game game-bottom">Harvard <span>40</span></li>\n
         <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>\n
         `;
    }
    console.log("HTML:", this.roundHtmlStr.toString());
    return(this.roundHtmlStr);
  }
```

Because I do not want to have to add another selector or *ngFor because it breaks the CSS due to adding another tag into the flexbox setup.

I have tried using nested selectors with divs, uls, etc.  They don't work because the css breaks. (Again unless you can come up with a different solution)

Solutions:
1.  How do I get the: return(this.roundHtmlStr); when it passes it back to the interpolation {{ getRoundHtml(roundIndex)}} to not be wrapped in "";  It's basically wrapping the return value and the html is actually displaying the text and not the html rendering.

2. Display brackets where the css can follow the scheme and align the matches correctly for every round no matter how big or small the bracket is 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64... etc.  The problem in Angular is that the css cannot follow the flexbox grow rules because the selector tag gets in the middle to the process and breaks the css.

```
Round 1          Round 2 (small 4 team bracket)

Duke 79
-----------
           | Duke 76
           ----------
           |        |
-----------         |
UNC  72             |   ND (Winner)
                    |-----------
                    |
Virginia 79         |
-----------         |
           | ND 91  | 
           ----------
           |
-----------
ND  72
```

Comment: can you provide stackblitz or fiddle ?

Comment: For the first solution you could try using property binding `<ul [innerHTML]="htmlStr"></ul>` ([link](https://alligator.io/angular/innerhtml-binding-angular/))

Answer (score 0):

So I figure out a different solution.

1. I had to flatten the nested selectors and dump everything into one for package component removing the nested selectors from breaking the css.
2. I had to change the structure of the HTML to:
   div

Then just the match with ol and li for a single match so it could be repeated with for loop because each round loops and the each round has 2 to the n power of matches/2 so round one for 32 man has 16 matches and round two has 8 and so on.